# cannot create file chromium-win-32.7z

Tags: chromium, jxbrowser

jxbrowser is being used in my project.

```
String file=<path>+"data"+<pid>+<time in milliseconds>;
```

above file instance is passed to constructor of BrowserContextParams

```
BrowserContextParams bcp=new BrowserContextParams(file);
BrowserContext context=new BrowserContext(bcp);
```

cannot create file chromium-win-32.7z runtime exception is coming while BrowserContext is being instatiated.

I am new to chromium and unable to understand why this error is coming in instantiation.Please provide some pointers.
Please ignore generic code given in file name

Comment: have u solved it out? I think you haven't extracted it properly.

Answer (score 1):

1) The jxbrowser-win32.jar, jxbrowser-win64.jar, jxbrowser-mac.jar, jxbrowser-linux64.jar libraries are part of JxBrowser library. They contain Chromium binaries for the corresponding platform. At first run, JxBrowser extracts the binaries from appropriate JAR file into user’s temp directory on macOS and Linux, and AppData\Local\JxBrowser on Windows.
Please make sure that the folder, where binaries are extracted to, has write permissions.

2) You can manually extract, for example, the library jxbrowser-win32-6.22.2.jar (depending on your OS). Then before the first JxBrowser run - call *System.setProperty("jxbrowser.chromium.dir", "")*